# Javascript automatic next image

Tags: javascript, image, slideshow

I created this site which uses a simple javascript function to show images based on the user mousing over or clicking numbered boxes on the right. Now after testing it's been determined that an automatic slideshow should be added on top of this, so that next image will show after a few seconds.

http://www.philippedollo.com/photo/fineart/f_amw.htm

Is there a way to amend this code easily to make it happen easily? --

```
function showPic(whichpic) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        document.getElementById('placeholder').src = whichpic.href;
        if (whichpic.title) {
            document.getElementById('desc').childNodes[0].nodeValue = whichpic.title;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('desc').childNodes[0].nodeValue = whichpic.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with jQuery too, it would be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setInterval).

```
function getNextPic()
{
    // ???
}

setInterval(function ()
{
    showPic(getNextPic());
}, 3000); // 3 seconds
```

There's no need for the `if(document.getElementById)` check, since the function is 100% cross-browser.

```
function showPic(whichpic)
{
    document.getElementById('placeholder').src = whichpic.href;

    document.getElementById('desc').childNodes[0].nodeValue = whichpic.title ?
        whichpic.title : whichpic.childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you, I tested it and it works fine on my end.

```
var curPic,
    gallery,
    pics;

function cyclePic(){
    if(curPic < pics.length){
        showPic(pics[curPic]);
    }
    curPic++;
    setTimeout(cyclePic,5000);
}

function showPic (whichpic) {
     if (document.getElementById) {
      document.getElementById('placeholder').src = whichpic.href;
      if (whichpic.title) {
       document.getElementById('desc').childNodes[0].nodeValue = whichpic.title;
      } else {
       document.getElementById('desc').childNodes[0].nodeValue = whichpic.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      }
      return false;
     } else {
      return true;
     }
}

window.onload = function(){
    curPic = 0,
    gallery = document.getElementById("gallery"),
    pics = gallery.getElementsByTagName("a");
    cyclePic();
}
```

Comment: You can replace `setTimeout(function(){cyclePic()},5000);` with `setTimeout(cyclePic, 5000);`.

Comment: that works for automatically forcing the slideshow, but I can't use the boxes to view other photos.

Comment: @user784576 Hmm Boxes should still work.. Only thing is it doesn't apply the highlighted styles to them. What error are you getting? Also it would be good to assign the interval and clear it when an image is hovered over to stop the cycling.

Comment: it works now, perfectly. Before there was no change when the boxes were moused over. The only strange bit now is that it seems like if I interrupt the automatic next image function by mousing over a box, the next function doesn't restart. Or maybe the function just peters out after a while on the page?